# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Could not verify SSL certificate for: https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-c2dm

I am getting [C2DMReg] handleRequest caught

> org.apache.http.auth.AuthenticationException

while trying to get the registration id from google server. Here is the logcat trace:

```
02-24 19:10:26.951: WARN/DefaultRequestDirector(122): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}
02-24 19:10:26.969: DEBUG/C2DMRegistrar(122): [C2DMRegistrar.24] register: http error 401
02-24 19:10:26.969: ERROR/C2DMRegistrar(122): [C2DMReg] handleRequest caught org.apache.http.auth.AuthenticationException
```

But I am able to get the registration id.But when I try to send the msg to device, I get an exception that is

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Could not verify SSL certificate
>   for: https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send

What can be the reason ? Its been 24 hours I registered my email id for C2DM service. I got their mail.But still it does not work.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the part of your code which makes the HTTP call?  With that information, we might be able to identify where the issue lies.

Answer (score 0):

It seem that Android device c2dm accepts only *.apis.google.com certificates. Try setting a fake HostnameVerifier as described here:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-c2dm/browse_thread/thread/49e902657d76a530

**Update:**

There is a project called [ChromeToPhone](http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/) which sends URLs from browser plugin to AppEngine backend and then via C2DM to Android phone.

Probably it would help to look at their source to see how they implemented C2DM on AppEngine: http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fappengine

Comment: Firs of all, thanks for your reply Peter.I tried to use the code described in the given link but HostVerifier is not supported by google app engine. My server side application uses google app engine just like chrometophone.

Comment: There is a project, ChromeToPhone, which sends messages from AppEngine to C2DM. Best to see how they do it. I updated the post.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your reply. But I have mentioned in my comment also that I am doing the same as to ChromeToPhone.But still I am not able to make it work.